# Displaying blank in a TemplateField if with two fields if one is null

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have combined two sets of datafields into one TemplateField in a gridview. If one of the fields is null, it should display nothing, however if the second field does contain some data, it should show the $x.xx of first amount on the first line & on second line show $x.xx of second amount. As of now, if it is null it will just show $0.00 in the second line (due to `String.format`).

As you can see in the code below, the two fields I speak of are `CarrierPayAmount` and `ExtraPay1Amount`.

Can anyone give me some syntax help here please? I have tried hacking away at it a bit, but cannot get it working as it should. I think this can be done with `if(eval("val") is DBnull.val` somehow.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="CarrierName" HeaderText="Carrier" SortExpression="CarrierName" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Charge">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%#String.Format("{0:c} {1:c}", Eval("CarrierPayAmount"), Eval("ExtraPay1Amount"))%>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `?:` conditional operator

Your code will be something like this:

```
<%#String.Format("{0:c} {1:c}", Eval("CarrierPayAmount").ToString() == null ? "" : Eval("CarrierPayAmount").ToString(), Eval("ExtraPay1Amount").ToString() == null ? "" : Eval("CarrierPayAmount").ToString())%>
```